# i want to secure insert query

Tags: php, security, mysqli, prepared-statement

some user inputs to assign values to the query.

```
 $builder_name    = $_POST['name'];
    $builder_city    = $_POST['city'];
    $builder_address = $_POST['address'];
    $builder_contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $builder_fax     = $_POST['fax'];
```

i have this insert query in my script .

```
$query = "INSERT INTO builders SET builder_name='".$builder_name."', builder_city='".$builder_city."',builder_address='".$builder_address."',builder_phone='".$builder_contact."',builder_fax='".$builder_fax."',builder_logo='".$targetfile."'";
```

i want to secure it with prepare statement.so how can i ?

Comment: Just like the linked question:)

Comment: query is a little bit different.in that link query is INSERT(table) and  Values() but  my query just like this INSERT table SET Values ..i mean all in one ..table column="' $value'"